# Translating to math notation from English specifically from Fundamental Alg.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I apologize if this is an incorrectly made question. 1st time posting here.

Anyway, I'm a programmer starting the (very) math heavy Fundamental Algorithms by Donald Knuth. In order to prepare myself for the later "math-y" chapters, I'm taking notes where I translate a piece of text from a section to mathematical notation so I can quickly reference later. My math notation skills are lacking to say the least though. How would one go about translating the below example?

Here is the example (From Section 1.1):

"We have quadruple $(Q,I,\Omega,f)$, in which $Q$ is a set containing subsets $I$ and $\Omega$ and $f$ is a function from $Q$ into itself. Furthermore $f$ should leave $\Omega$ pointwise fixed; that is, $f(q)$ should equal $q$ for all elements $q$ of $\Omega$."

So I want to convert that statement to mathematical notation, I don't have my attempts in front of me I took from last night but I tried starting with expressing "$f(q)$ should equal $q$ for all elements $q$ of $\Omega$." correctly first which I had trouble with:

$$
\{q\in\Omega\vert f(q)=q\}
$$

I'm a little confused with the correct notation for "for all elements" because I've seen the symbol $\forall$ to mean "for all". also I know $\vert$ stands for "such that", it seems like I'd use that in this case but I'm not sure.

My question is, how do you go about translating something like the quote above, and is there any good reference of mathematical notation?

I feel like doing this would make my parsing and grokking of strictly math notation significantly better which is why I'm doing it this way.

Comment: ($\forall q \in \Omega) f(q) = q$? This reads "for all $q$ in $\Omega$ we have $f(q) = q$".

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but more of a suggestion to think about. If your goal in this translation is to be able to "quickly reference later" I personally find that mixing math statements with common English is the best way to go. Trying to translate literally everything into symbols sometimes ends up making things more confusing and obtuse.

Comment: yeah that's probably not the best way to have worded it. My notes are marked with where in the book their from. My writing the mathematical notation is strictly for me to get better at it. I do mix it with English but I'd still like to represent the above mathematically

Comment: @ZainPatel is that correct? To me it looks like the parenthesizes have different meanings depending on context and location? Seems confusing

Comment: It’s common (but not universal) to parenthesize the quantification, perhaps just to set it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the objective part of your question:

1. "$Q$ is a set containing subsets $I$ and $\Omega$" is the same as $I, \Omega \subseteq Q$
2. "$f$ is a function from $Q$ into itself" is the same as $f: Q \rightarrow Q$
3. "$f$ should leave $\Omega$ pointwise fixed" is the same as $\forall q \in \Omega,\,f(q) = q$

You have written $\{q\in\Omega\vert f(q)=q\}$ which is the same as "the set of all elements $q$ in the set $\Omega$ such that $f$ maps them to themselves".

To answer the subjective part of your question: I wouldn't recommend trying to 'translate' everything into mathematical notation because that would just make it confusing and hard to understand, even for people who are used to reading mathematical notation. However, it is true that some things are more concisely and/or precisely expressed using mathematical notation, and it is good that you are trying to learn how to do so.

As you come across more and more mathematical notation in e.g. papers or online sources like Math.SE you will learn certain 'idioms' for how things are usually expressed (like @Lubin's comment on the question). A dictionary of sorts can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject).

Comment: Um, no. Subsets would be $I\subseteq Q$ and $\Omega\subseteq Q$. $\in$ is for _elements_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh oops this is embarrassing. Thanks for pointing it out, edited.

Comment: Yeah I guess what I'm trying to accomplish is being able express my computer science work (personal projects/ideas) as math rather than obscure drawings, flow charts and mental models. This is difficult without knowing the notation so that's why I thought 'translating' would be a good idea to hammer in that knowledge. Thanks for the answer!